# Best way for scheduling an asynchronous httpClient

Tags: vb.net, async-await, httpclient

I have list of urls to be scraped every minute, and then be saved on hard disk. Now, i'm using a timer control and i've divided url list to smaller packs. In each tick of timer, i await an async method to get that smaller pack of urls, as follows:

```
 Private Async Sub timerGetData_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles timerGetData.Tick
    tickCounter += 1
    Dim UrlPorcessed_Tick, failedUrl_Tick As Integer, StartTime_Round As String
    If tickCounter > tickNum Then
        tickCounter = 1
        roundCounter += 1      ' one round of getting all urls, i.e 1 minute
        processedUrlCounter = 0
        failedUrlCounter = 0
        UrlPorcessed_Tick = 0
        failedUrl_Tick = 0
        StartTime_Round = Now.TimeOfDay.ToString

        FailedUrls = New List(Of String)
        FailedUrlsReason = New List(Of String)
    End If


    Dim firstIndex, lastIndex As Integer
    firstIndex = (tickCounter - 1) * TickUrlsNum
    lastIndex = If(firstIndex + TickUrlsNum - 1 > AllUrlsNum - 1, AllUrlsNum - 1, firstIndex + TickUrlsNum - 1)
    Dim logText As String

    For rr = firstIndex To lastIndex

        Dim r As DataRow = UrlsDt(rr)

        Dim address As String = r("url")
        Dim strFull As String = ""
        Try
            strFull = Await GetTseData(address2)
        Catch ex As TaskCanceledException
            logText = ex.ToString
        End Try

        If strFull = String.Empty Then
            failedUrl_Tick += 1
            FailedUrls.Add(address)
            FailedUrlsReason.Add("Empty response" & " -- t1: " & t1 & "  -- t2: " & t2)
            Continue For
        End If

       Dim r2 As Integer = FillDb(dbFile, address, strFull)
        If r2 = 0 Then
            failedUrl_Tick += 1
            FailedUrls.Add(address)
            FailedUrlsReason.Add("Problem in Url Process")
            Continue For
        End If

        UrlPorcessed_Tick += 1
    Next

    processedUrlCounter += UrlPorcessed_Tick
    processedUrlCounter_Total += UrlPorcessed_Tick
    failedUrlCounter += failedUrl_Tick
    failedUrlCounter_Total += failedUrl_Tick

    logText = StartTime_GetData + vbNewLine + "-------------------" + vbNewLine + _
             "round time: " + StartTime_Round + vbNewLine + _
              "round counter: " + roundCounter.ToString + vbNewLine + _
             "tick counter: " + tickCounter.ToString + vbNewLine + _
             "All Urls Number:" + AllUrlsNum.ToString + vbNewLine + _
              "from/to:" + firstIndex.ToString + "/" + lastIndex.ToString + vbNewLine + _
             "Urls processed (in round)/Total:" + processedUrlCounter.ToString & "/" & processedUrlCounter_Total & vbNewLine & _
             "Urls failed (in round)/Total:" + failedUrlCounter.ToString & "/" & failedUrlCounter_Total & vbNewLine & _
             "failed percentage (in round)/Total:" & Math.Round(failedUrlCounter / (failedUrlCounter + processedUrlCounter) * 100, 1).ToString & "/" & Math.Round(failedUrlCounter_Total / (failedUrlCounter_Total + processedUrlCounter_Total) * 100, 1).ToString & vbNewLine

    If tickCounter = tickNum Then
                    logText += vbNewLine & "Unsuccessful Urls: " & vbNewLine
        For i = 0 To FailedUrls.Count - 1
            logText += FailedUrls(i) & ", " & FailedUrlsReason(i) & vbNewLine
        Next
        System.IO.File.AppendAllText(logFile, logText)
    End If



End Sub
```

This is method that gets data from internet:

```
Private Async Function GetData(address As String) As Task(Of String)

    Dim response As HttpResponseMessage = Await hc.GetAsync(address)
    Dim Str = Await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync()
    If response.IsSuccessStatusCode Then
        Return Str
    Else
        Return ""
    End If

End Function
```

and, HttpClient is created in from_load. Now, My question is that

1. Am i doing work in efficient way? (I need this operation to be async, because in another part of program, i'm reading the result from hard disk)
2. In above code, i have some problems in logging successful an failed (= empty response) urls. It sounds because of using async mechansim, i get smaller urls in log file. Let's say All urls = 1000, i see 800 successful and 100 failed url in log file. How can i overcome this problem?

Comment: Re your second question, have you tried stepping through it in a debugger to check for any obvious errors?  There's nothing that jumps out at me as conceptually wrong that would lead to the behavior that you observe.

Comment: Thanks @craig. No, i don't see any errors. It sounds for me that this problem occurs because some of getting data async in last timer tick has not finished. It means in new tick, i have started new connections and have some open connections from last tick.

Comment: If you want to analyze along those lines, the thing to remember is, your potential interruption points are `Await`s.  You can still get unexpected behavior from reentrancy, but there are fewer potential points of contention than with multithreaded code.

Comment: If you're concerned about overlapping calls, As a trial what if you where to slow things down a bit? Make sure it's got the time to complete all 1000 urls and that works as expected

Comment: Thanks a lot. Any idea about 1st question? I'm not much familiar with multithreading. Isn't it better to put async in another thread, while main thread is devote to reading database?